# Summing of individual numbers in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum

I am trying to find the sum of the individual values in an array, not sum the numbers together. For example

If I have array = ["123","324","644"]
I need it to return the sums of each value so the result should be

6,9,and 14 respectively. Since 1+2+3=6 etc...
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

```
array.map { |str| str.each_char.map(&:to_i).reduce(&:+) }
```

For every string in array: turn each character into an integer and sum them up.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = ["123","324","644"]
array.map do |num_string|
  num_string.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end
=> [6, 9, 14]
```

Comment: Did you notice @Amadan used `each_char` rather than `chars`? `each_char` is preferred because it returns an enumerator, whereas `chars` returns an array, which occupies space. Think of an enumerator as a set of rules for feeding values to the block, values that are computed as needed. Here those values are the elements of `array`. Addenum: I just read @Santosh's comment about `chars` being the faster of the two here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more efficient, since map is not used on `chars`

```
array.map { |str| str.chars.inject(0){|s,x| s+= x.to_i } }
# => [6, 9, 14]
```

Comment: Yup. `each_char.inject...` is even faster (by 17% on my `irb`).

Comment: Weird indeed. On 40M-char string,  utime for `chars`: 13.84s, for `each_char`: 8.72s (OS/X, MRI 2.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
2.2.0 :067 > array.each {|a| print a.split("").inject {|sum, x| sum.to_i+x.to_i}, "\t"}
6   9   14   => ["123", "324", "644"]
```

if you want to add these values to another array,

```
2.2.0 :068 > marray = []
 => [] 
2.2.0 :069 > array.each {|a| marray << a.split("").inject {|sum, x| sum.to_i+x.to_i}}
 => ["123", "324", "644"] 
2.2.0 :070 > marray
 => [6, 9, 14]
```